# Poor UNION ALL performance in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, union, union-all

I have a database with rows like the following:

```
+------------+---------+------------+-------+
| continent  | country | city       | value |
+------------+---------+------------+-------+
| Asia       | China   | Beijing    | 3     |
| ...        | ...     | ...        | ...   |
| N. America | USA     | D.C        | 7     |
| ....       | ....    | ....       | ....  |
```

In order to generate a treemap visualization, I need to work this into a table with the following shape:

```
+-----+------------+-------+
| uid | parent-uid | value |
+-----+------------+-------+
```

In this case, `Asia` is the "parent" for `China`, which is the "parent" for `Beijing`. So for those three you'd have **something** like:

```
+---------+--------+-----+
| Beijing | China  | 3   |
| China   | Asia   | ... |
| Asia    | global | ... |
+---------+--------+-----+
```

The "value" for `China` needs to be an aggregate of all child values. Similarly the value of `Asia` needs to be an aggregate of all child values.

To accomplish this purely in SQL I created the following three queries and combined them with `UNION ALL`:

```
# City-level:
SELECT
     CONCAT(continent, "-", country, "-", city) as uid,
     CONCAT(continent, "-", country) as parentuid,
     value
FROM
     table

UNION ALL

# Country-level
SELECT
     CONCAT(continent, "-", country) as uid,
     continent as parentuid,
     SUM(value) as value
FROM
     table
GROUP BY
     country

UNION ALL

# Continent-level
SELECT
    continent as uid,
    "global" as parentuid,
    SUM(value) as value
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    continent
```

Each of the individual queries completes in milliseconds. City-level, country-level, and continent-level all return results in < 0.01 seconds

When I union them all together it suddenly takes 8 seconds to get results!

I've tried Googling the issues but everything just says "Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`" (I already am)

I considered that it might not have enough RAM to build the temporary results table so it's disk trashing, but I don't know how to increase the memory limit. I tried bumping `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 1GB (1073741824) but it didn't help

Comment: Are you sure that it is the query that is slowing things down and not the passing or rendering of the result set?

Comment: How many rows in the table?  How many rows in the output?

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  Which version of mysql are you using?  (There may be an issue with the implicit temp table(s) involved here.)

Comment: Can you tell if you are I/O bound when it takes 8 seconds?

Comment: "< 0.01 sec" probably means the Query cache is involved. Please re-time using `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `select`, selects all rows in the table then getting the first row is very fast but fetching all rows will take very much time(the mysql workbench append `limit 1000` to end of the query by default).

To test that fetching all rows take more time, try following query and say us the time it consumes:

```
select * from (
SELECT
     CONCAT(continent, "-", country, "-", city) as uid,
     CONCAT(continent, "-", country) as parentuid,
     value
FROM
     table
) t1;
```

If it takes almost 8 seconds then your union have no problem. And for improve performance you must limit rows by using where clause.

I hope it could help.

Comment: Sure enough, this explains the performance. I used the `select * from (...)` query you recommended and it went from 0.0027 seconds to 9.3 seconds. Guess MySQL workbench was just confusing me.

Comment: @stevendesu Glad, I could help

Answer (score 1):

I guess my question is: what's wrong with [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)?

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS('-',continent,country,city) as uid,
    CONCAT_WS('-',continent,COALESCE(country,'global')) as parentuid,
    value
FROM (
    SELECT continent, country, city, SUM(value) as value
    FROM table
    GROUP BY continent, country, city WITH ROLLUP
) t1
WHERE t1.continent IS NOT NULL;
```

I may not have the [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) calls correct, especially if you have cities or countries named `''`, but I have to think this would be faster.  The WHERE clause is just there to remove the overall summary.

Here's the example for `WITH ROLLUP` from the MySQL doc to help explain what it does:

```
mysql> SELECT year, country, product, SUM(profit)
    -> FROM sales
    -> GROUP BY year, country, product WITH ROLLUP;
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
| year | country | product    | SUM(profit) |
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
| 2000 | Finland | Computer   |        1500 |
| 2000 | Finland | Phone      |         100 |
| 2000 | Finland | NULL       |        1600 |
| 2000 | India   | Calculator |         150 |
| 2000 | India   | Computer   |        1200 |
| 2000 | India   | NULL       |        1350 |
| 2000 | USA     | Calculator |          75 |
| 2000 | USA     | Computer   |        1500 |
| 2000 | USA     | NULL       |        1575 |
| 2000 | NULL    | NULL       |        4525 |
| 2001 | Finland | Phone      |          10 |
| 2001 | Finland | NULL       |          10 |
| 2001 | USA     | Calculator |          50 |
| 2001 | USA     | Computer   |        2700 |
| 2001 | USA     | TV         |         250 |
| 2001 | USA     | NULL       |        3000 |
| 2001 | NULL    | NULL       |        3010 |
| NULL | NULL    | NULL       |        7535 |
+------+---------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: `WITH ROLLUP` may do exactly what I need (I wasn't aware this was even a thing). I'll try it out Monday and see what happens

Comment: Just tested this and it actually took slightly **longer** using `WITH ROLLUP` than my `UNION ALL` solution (~11 seconds instead of ~8 seconds). I suspect it's because at the lowest level (when not using a group-by) I was selecting the value directly instead of selecting an aggregate. Oddly enough, `WITH ROLLUP` returned 275000 rows whereas my `UNION ALL` solution returned 250000 rows. I don't know what the new rows are all about. Maybe some quirk with Australia (continent / country are the same)?